# I need to sign in to my Google Account but can't as no link available so can't use tablet

Tags: tablet

I haven't used my tablet for a while & in that time I've changed my google account  password. 
I can only think that this is why it won't let me access anything but when it tells me that I need to sign in to my Google account I don't know how to do it. Feel a bit of an idiot!!

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple (its fine, everyone is a bit of an idiot). All you have to do is go to the gmail app. Then reload your mail. It will tell you that your sign in details are out of date. Click on change (or a similar option) and you're done!

Comment: Thanks Rahul but still being an idiot! Sorry. Do you mean  by using the icon on my screen or elsewhere? Also how do I reload my email? Complete beginner!

Comment: No problem ! All you have to do is drag the top email on your list down. Dragging the list down automatically updates all mail.

Comment: If you still cannot do it, go to the gmail app, click on the icon on the top left, go to the bottom of the list and go to settings. Then, check the box saying 'sync gmail'. Connect to a wifi or 3g/4g network and it should update and refresh